# Blender Flipped Normal Object Won't Render Material

Tags: rendering

I have a subdivided cube (now a sphere) with materials (diffuse, gloss, emission, and ambient occlusion) on it. I put objects inside of it, and flipped the normals to create a "world inside the sphere). When rendering in viewport I,can see all materials. For final Cycles render the inside,of the sphere renders gray, and doesnt render the material at all. How can I fix this?

the left is how it should look with the inside of the white sphere visible behind the objects (render preview in viewort shading). the right is the final render result, which incorrectly shows like grat behind the objects. How do i get the final render result to also show white?

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can see?

Comment: photo added of the issue!

Comment: is the camera inside the sphere?

Comment: Yes the camera is inside the sphere